How i can set margin in -(Minus)?
in my app i use container i push the container to the top side so i want to set minus margin but is not work
            Container(
                  margin:const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, -20, 5, 0),
                  child:const Text(
                  'MyContainer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: black, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
             ) 


You can't do it directly with EdgeInsets as it doesn't support negative values. Instead, you can use Transform widget to achieve the effect of negative margins.

Wrap Container with Transform.translate.
Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(5, -20), 
            child: Container(
            child: const Text(
                'MyContainer',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          )

